# If $f$ is differentiable at $P_0(x_0,y_0)$, can this imply $f_x',f_y'$ exsits in a neigborhood of $P_0$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> If $f$ is differentiable at $P_0(x_0,y_0)$, can this imply $f_x',f_y'$ exsits in a neigborhood of $P_0$?

Clearly, $f_x'(x_0,y_0),f_y'(x_0,y_0)$ exists, but what about the existence of $f_x',f_y'$ in a neigborhood of $P_0$? I guess it is false, but could not figure out a counterexample.

Comment: In one-dimension, an obvious counterexample is $f(x)=x^2$ if $x$ is rational and $0$ otherwise. Use this as motivation.